# working with slidetoggle in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having some issues when i am trying to work with slidetoggle property in jquery. 
What i would like to accomplish is:

- i have a parent div with a dynamic number of children divs.
- when the page is loaded the first div is toggled (open).
- i would like to when i click on one of children divs , the one that i clicked should toggle open and any other which is open to toggle closed.

I've tried this:

```
   $i++;
   $("#items"+ $i).click(function(){
            $("#items'.$i.'-submenu").slideToggle('slow', function() {
                 if ( $("#item'.$i.'s-submenu").is(":visible")) {
                      $("#items'.$i.'").css("border-right","none");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#items'.$i.'").css("border-style","solid solid solid solid");
                $("#items'.$i.'").css("border-right-width","1px");
            }
            });

            return false;
        });
```

Later edit:

The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="item">Click here </div>
<div class="content">There it goes the hidden content</div>
<div class="item">Click here </div>
<div class="content">There it goes the hidden content</div>
<div class="item">Click here </div>
<div class="content">There it goes the hidden content</div>
<div class="item">Click here </div>
<div class="content">There it goes the hidden content</div>
<div class="item">Click here </div>
<div class="content">There it goes the hidden content</div>
<div class="item">Click here </div>
<div class="content">There it goes the hidden content</div>
<div class="item">Click here </div>
<div class="content">There it goes the hidden content</div>
<div class="item">Click here </div>
<div class="content">There it goes the hidden content</div>
 .....................
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the HTML that goes with that strangeness?

Comment: Why are the quotes on `\'slow\'` escaped?

Comment: code has syntax errors does fixing those help? Missing selector quotes, escaping etc If not provide some html

Comment: @adeano for every div i have something like <div id="items'.$i.'">Button</div><div id="items'.$i.'-submenu">Text</div>

Comment: you want an accordian? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: you're using to much php. dont use periods to concat strings, use + symbols

Comment: @PulkitMittal something like that!

Comment: Give all your elements common class names. The way you are using dynamically generated ID's you would have to write the same block of code for each and every master elemnt ID. Provide some legitimate HTML with enough structure to show several layers...  source html not php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***UPDATED USING YOUR HTML***
>
> New jQuery

```
$(".item").click(function(e) {
    $(this).next(".content").slideToggle().siblings(".content").each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) $(this).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

### New jsFiddle Here

---

You could just use [jQueryUI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/), however if you want to do it yourself it is not hard.

## See jsFiddle Here

The code would be like below:

> Basic HTML Layout

```
<div class="item">
    <p class="clickable">Click Here</p>
    <div class="content">
        I'm open!
        <br />
        I'm open!
        <br />
        I'm open!
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="item">
    <p class="clickable">Click Here</p>
    <div class="content">
        I'm open!
        <br />
        I'm open!
        <br />
        I'm open!
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="item">
    <p class="clickable">Click Here</p>
    <div class="content">
        I'm open!
        <br />
        I'm open!
        <br />
        I'm open!
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="item">
    <p class="clickable">Click Here</p>
    <div class="content">
        I'm open!
        <br />
        I'm open!
        <br />
        I'm open!
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="item">
    <p class="clickable">Click Here</p>
    <div class="content">
        I'm open!
        <br />
        I'm open!
        <br />
        I'm open!
    </div>
</div>​
```

> a lil CSS

```
.content { display: none; }
.clickable { cursor: pointer; }
```

> Finally some jQuery

```
$(".item").click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings().each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).children(".content").is(":visible")) $(this).children(".content").slideToggle();
    });
    $(this).children(".content").slideToggle();
});​
```

​

Comment: it does seems to work but i do not have the content class as a children, it is a div as an item...

Comment: you can change it to suit your needs, i just a gave a base manner upon which to work with. post you html to your question and perhaps i can make it more precise.

Comment: question edited.... your code iterates through children divs  so that is my question actually , how could i iterate through my divs provided up the html code.